# JndiObjectFactoryBean could not be refered to SqlSessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, jndi, mybatis, spring-framework-beans

When I using JndiObjectFactoryBean as dataSource in applicationContext.xml, it seems that sqlSessionFactory's property could not refer to this dataSource...What should I do to solve it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADsB2.png)

My codes are show below:

```
<bean id="dataSource"  class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jndi/smbms"/>
</bean>


<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml"/>

    <!--<property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:cn/smbms/dao/**/*.xml"/>-->
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="cn.smbms.dao"/>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="cn.smbms.service"/>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
<!--<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>-->
```